# Align absolute positioned title

Tags: html, css

How to center align an absolute positioned title that cant be of a fixed width?
Some titles can have 3 letters, but also 5,6 words.
So this code doesnt work properly

```
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:-205px;
    left: 50%;
```

White container is the title I'm trying to align to the center of an image
http://s29.postimg.org/57cicvi2f/aaaaaaaa.jpg

Comment: It depends of your site appearance. Can you share some screenshot etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First answer by @Nate is a good method to start with.  Stretch the title via (left and right of 0) and apply text-align of center.

If shrinkwrapping behavior of an absolute block is important (i.e., it is desirable for the title to stretch only as far as its contents), then you can use translateX() transform method: http://jsfiddle.net/8h9Th/.

HTML:

```
<h1>Site Title</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font: bold 24px/2 Sans-Serif;
    padding: 0 24px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: this works, thanks! i have also put white-space: nowrap; so title wont break, if anyone reads this later

Answer (score 1):

you would need to give it a left position and a right position which are equal and then use `text-align:center` Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<div class="title">This Is A Title</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title {
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   text-align:center.;
}
```